# Grapevine restserver not reacheable with useHTTPS

Tags: c#, rest, https, grapevine

When I set the useHttps property to true, I am not able to reach the server.

The instantiation of the server looks like this:

```
class Listener
{
    RestServer server;
    public Listener()
    {
        server = new RestServer();

        server.Port = "8137";
        server.UseHttps = true;
    }
}
```

The server starts, and the console input tells me that it listens on https://localhost:8137, but when I try and make a request (in Fiddler), I get the error message: 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed.

```
The connection to 'localhost' failed. 
System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to localhost (for #38) failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

For me it looks like there is a problem with the HTTPS and perhaps the certificate. But where am I able to specify the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grapevine is build on top of the .NET `HttpListener` class. What you have already in your original post is sufficient **from a code perspective**. However, there is more that will need to be done on the machine the server is running on for this to work.

- See [the HttpListener docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), especially the notes at the bottom of the page.
- There is an excellent [writeup on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support) for enabling https support for localhost.
- If you run into [problems like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726938), I would suggest searching on StackOverflow, as the issue will have nothing to do with Grapevine, and everything to do with the certificate setup.

Comment: Yes, I actually realized this afterwards. The problem was that I needed to tell Windows to use the certificate for communication on the given port. This post has the details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11457719/943170