# How to post a request to Java servlet from .net

Tags: c#, .net, ccavenue

How to post the following data to servlet url:

Data:

```
enc_request=63957FB55DD6E7B968A7588763E08B240878046EF2F520C44BBC63FB9CCE726209A4734877F5904445591304ABB2F5E598B951E39EAFB9A24584B00590ADB077ADE5E8C444EAC5A250B1EA96F68D22E44EA2515401C2CD753DBA91BD0E7DFE7341BE1E7B7550&access_code=8JXENNSSBEZCU8KQ&command=confirmOrder&request_type=XML&response_type=XML&version=1.1
```

Url:

```
"https://logintest.ccavenue.com/apis/servlet/DoWebTrans";
```

I tried https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df76fbfa-2931-4c9f-8671-785307243f62/post-request-to-a-java-servlet-and-process-httpresponse-using-net?forum=wcf . But I'm getting the error: [C# System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886223/c-sharp-system-net-webexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpe)

Below is my code:

```
                 StringBuilder sbQueryString = new StringBuilder();
                 CCACrypto ccaCrypto = new CCACrypto();
                 string workingKey = "14A246E9D4341159638AC8EB776F3BE6";

//put     in the   32bit alpha numeric key in the quotes provided here

                sbQueryString.Append("enc_request=");
                sbQueryString.Append(ccaCrypto.Encrypt(GenerateOrderXml(appointmentId), workingKey));
                sbQueryString.Append("&");
                sbQueryString.Append("access_code=");
                sbQueryString.Append("AVQJ68DL46BW00JQWB");
                sbQueryString.Append("&");
                sbQueryString.Append("Command=");
                sbQueryString.Append("cancelOrder");
                sbQueryString.Append("&");
                sbQueryString.Append("request_type=XML&response_type=XML");
                sbQueryString.Append("&");
                sbQueryString.Append("version=1.1");
                //Response.Redirect("../ccAvenue/ccavAPIHandler.aspx?" + sbQueryString.ToString(), false);

                //string url = "https://logintest.ccavenue.com/apis/servlet/DoWebTrans";
                string url = "https://180.179.175.17/apis/servlet/DoWebTrans";

                // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.   
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                // Set the Method property of the request to POST.  
                request.Method = "POST";
                // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  
                string postData = sbQueryString.ToString();
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.  
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.  
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Get the request stream.  
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.  
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.  
                dataStream.Close();
                // Get the response.  
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                // Display the status.  
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.  
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.  
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the content.  
                Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                // Clean up the streams.  
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
```

Comment: I get 503 error - service unavailable. This error is not related to the way you post the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try simplifying your code by using a [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "enc_request", "63957FB55DD6E7B968A7588763E08B240878046EF2F520C44BBC63FB9CCE726209A4734877F5904445591304ABB2F5E598B951E39EAFB9A24584B00590ADB077ADE5E8C444EAC5A250B1EA96F68D22E44EA2515401C2CD753DBA91BD0E7DFE7341BE1E7B7550" },
        { "access_code", "8JXENNSSBEZCU8KQ" },
        { "command", "confirmOrder" },
        { "request_type", "XML" },
        { "response_type", "XML" },
        { "version", "1.1" },
    };
    var url = "https://logintest.ccavenue.com/apis/servlet/DoWebTrans";
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues(url, data);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the error: C# System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Comment: Then, there's probably some issue with the server. Maybe if some invalid parameters are sent the server closes the connection. You might need to consult the documentation of the remote service you are using. The client code is fine.