# REST request getting blocked?

Tags: c#, restsharp

Using RestRequest to a REST endpoint (Asana). Some machines get the request returned properly and some don't get anything. Doing more troubleshooting I **think** that the machines that do not get responses have IE as their default browser.

If I test the url manually in a Chrome browser I get the response. If I test in the IE browser then I get a "Do you want to Open or Save" prompt. I=My theory is that an IE setting of somekind is blocking the request with this question and since it is an app it just blocks.

My code is simple:

```
        var client = new RestClient(@"https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/99999999999999/tasks/search);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + asanaToken);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: The systems default browser shouldn't be relevant to how this code functions.

Comment: You need to do more debugging than just saying "some don't get anything". There will be a response with some detail in it, but this code isn't enough to diagnose it. And completely agree with @Amy, the browser makes no difference at all.

Comment: does asana use certificates not installed (their CA) in some of the machines?

Comment: @DavidG - Yes, I get what you are saying. It is only happening on certain machines. I think I am going to have to create a version that logs stuff and install it on their machine. I cannot duplicate the result on my dev machine.

Comment: @EricSnyder Basic logging should be part of any application by default. It's easier to solve issues with more diagnostic data.

Comment: @Amy - Completely agree. I was being lazy. The error I am getting is: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Comment: @bradbury9 - Don't think so.

Comment: @EricSnyder That sounds like a TLS version issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627977/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send

Comment: See @Amy pointer to [this solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627977/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send) Solved it!