# connection issue to azure cognitive search from asp.net mvc website

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a asp.net mvc website developed in .NET framework 4.7. getting connection issue from hosted website. can you please help

`An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Comment: We set out to bring the benefits of event-driven architectures and the productivity of functions to Kubernetes. The result is KEDA – Kubernetes-based event-driven autoscaling.

Comment: @Sajeetharan...What's the relevance of your comment?

Answer (score 2):

I usually face this error while debugging, but if you deploy this it will disappear. 
For debugging purpose, add following lines before calling external services. 
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;`

Comment: Hi Manish, I am facing this issue after deployment..it works fine in debugging mode..thanks for your reply

Comment: where is it hosted? might be some TLS issue.

Comment: Yes..hosted on a third party host provider

Comment: I get the same error after hosting the website on azure app service ( test environment)

Comment: have you tried ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol option? add those line and deploy. found similar thing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627977/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send