# Error on HTTPS based service: Underlying connection was closed, an unexpected error occured

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am getting an error while send the dataset to https based web service. The error is underlying connection was closed; An unexpected error occured on a send.
Kindly suggest me the appropriate solution.

Comment: First, we need more information to indicate your issue. Secondary, you can refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627977/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send) and [THIS](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/583133/theplusunderlyingplusconnectionpluswasplusclosed-3) to get some help.

Comment: What type of information need to share with u??

Comment: How the issue occurred? What the error message is showing? etc...

Comment: I need to push the Dataset to a service, previous it was working fine, but now a days it returned with error, Underlying connection was closed, an unexpected error occured