# asp.NET 4.8 WebRequest errors with "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssl, httpwebrequest, webrequest

On one particular website on my web server WebRequests have started throwing the following error: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

- My asp.NET website is running framework version 4.8.
- I am requesting a page on the same website that is doing the request.
- This code has been in place for years and has suddenly stopped working on this website
- This same code works fine on a different website running on the same webserver

Request code:

```
Dim myReq As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://example.com")
myReq.Method = "GET"

myReq.ContentType = "text/html; encoding='utf-32'"


Dim wr As System.Net.WebResponse = myReq.GetResponse()
Dim receiveStream As System.IO.Stream = wr.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)
Dim content As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

I have tried adding the following to the page doing the request, and the global.asax, but it did not work. It should not be required, though, because I am using .net 4.8:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Comment: Have you checked the DNS settings / HOSTS file entry for the affected site?

Comment: Think you might be on the right track with the security protocol.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627977/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send which suggests a few other additions

Comment: @RichardDeeming you are a diamond. That was the issue - for three days I've been looking at everything - as soon as you said that, I remembered adding a hosts value last week. Removed it and the error went away. Thank you! If you add as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is often an issue with the internal DNS or a HOSTS file entry. Either the server is resolving the site's domain to the wrong internal address, or it's trying to access the site's public address and confusing the router.

Comment: Thanks Richard, your insight saved me a huge headache.