# How to get Web Service Task to call SOAP API?

Tags: ssis

I've created an SSIS package calling SOAP API using Web Service Task. The HTTP connection works fine, the endpoint is reachable from the host the SSIS service is running, I've downloaded WSDL file but when I execute the package, I keep getting the very same error:

> [Web Service Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message:
>
> "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: The Web Service threw an error during method execution.
> The error is: Basic connection terminated: An unexpected sending error occurred..
> w Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection)
> w Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser taskVariableDispenser)
> w Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".

Got any idea how to get it to call the API?

Comment: My suggestion is: do not use SSIS to do anything other than copy data and call stored procedures. Libraries, debugging and maintenance are a nightmare in the script task. Use a more suitable language like .Net or even Powershell. Having said that, this post appears to indicate it could be an SSL issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627977/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send Keep in mind the error is so generic it's hard to tell.