# Enabling TLS 1.1/1.2 in MFC/ATL C++ app

Tags: .net, mfc, interop, atl

I have an ALT COM/MFC C++ app that does .NET interop into .NET 4.5 assemblies which are expected to use TLS 1.1/1.2 for backend channels. Any idea on how to setup such TLS support at the entry of the C++ app?

Doing it for pure .NET app is completely clear from here: [Is TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 enabled by default for .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920429/is-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-enabled-by-default-for-net-4-5-and-net-4-5-1).

Comment: Would [forcing by registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32892997/205233) also be an option?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and ref. Saw that option too during research but didn't want to do so yet. Afraid customer's 3rd party apps might be impacted. Just want to modify our services for now to be in compliance and will let the customer control when they want to turn off TLS 1.0. Most C++ solution seen out there are all about setting TLS for a specific connection/channel, not overall app domain. Going to try to interop out to a .NET assembly that then will set the protocol in C#. Hope that will work.