# Visual Basic - HTTPClient and API Request Issue

Tags: json, vb.net, dotnet-httpclient

As a returning developer (I've been in management for a long time!), I've been tasked with developing a module for our proprietary financial system (Visual Basic/ SQL Server) that will read large .CSV files containing customer information, convert them into JSON format, then submit them to an external party for processing via that company's API.

The conversion part was easy and I'm almost ready to go with it, but I can't establish connectivity to the external API.

There are two parts to the process: -

1. Submit login details (obfuscated here) and receive a Bearer Token from the API

   > {"username": "MadeUpUser","password": "Y66***uYj6%%YY"}
2. Submit JSON format customer info to API endpoint, using Bearer Token, receive confirmation

I've submitted both the login creds and my JSON-format data to the API via Postman and it works perfectly, however, when I try to login via my VB app using the `HTTPClient class`, I'm getting the follow exception (copied from the Exception class properties) :

> HResult = -2146233088
> StackTrace = "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)"
> InnerException = {"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}

It's clearly something I'm doing wrong programmatically or something I'm not doing and any help or advice offered will be greatly appreciated.

The code: (`AddLogEntry()` is a Sub I created to log events to a text file)

```
Private Async Function PostAsync(ByVal JSONString As String, EndPoint As String) As Task
    Dim APIuri As New Uri(EndPoint)

    Try
        With ZincClient
            .BaseAddress = APIuri
            .DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
            .DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
        End With

        Dim content As New Net.Http.StringContent(JSONString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        Dim response As Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage = Await ZincClient.PostAsync(APIuri, content)

        Dim result As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    Catch ex As Exception

        AddLogEntry("ERROR! - " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return

End Function
```

Comment: I don't see any signs in your code that you are using the bearer token. Can you post that code?

Comment: What System is this code run from? -- It would be interesting to see from where and how you call this method. Plus, what's in the comment above.

Comment: @tcarvin - at this stage, I need to POST my login details to get the Bearer Token from the host API before I can POST my customer data.

Comment: @Jimi - it's VB.Net - based module that comprises part of a larger system.

Comment: *System* means System: Windows 7 (SP1), Windows 10 (v.1803 / 1809 / 20H2), Windows Server 2008 R2 etc.

Comment: Update : I tested the above code against - https://httpbin.org/anything - and it worked, so I believe that as the 3rd party site I'm trying to POST to is HTTPS, that it's a Security Certificate issue that's the problem.

Comment: @Jimi - Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362 Build 18362

Comment: If you're using an older .NET Framework, see [Is TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 enabled by default for .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34920429/1115360)