# TLS1.2 and .Net Framework 4.5.2 issue

Tags: .net, tls1.2

We have a web application that is built on .Net Framework 4.5.2. An upgrade was done on one of the 3rd party servers by installing TSL1.2. Ever since, when trying to make a call to this 3rd party server, the following error is generated:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
    Stack Trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   Inner Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
    Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
    ----------------
    Inner Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

In all haste, I updated the web.config entries of the web application to reference runtime .net framework 4.6 and compilation framework 4.6.2 to address the issue.

My question is, why did .Net Framework 4.5.2 fail on the TSL1.2 upgrade?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default SecurityProtocol in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5)

Comment: Yeah, got my explanation from this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920429/is-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-enabled-by-default-for-net-4-5-and-net-4-5-1/45692875