# System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException - ActiveMQ NMS Connection Start() method giving exception in .Net 4.5 version

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic, amazon-mq, nms

I am getting error while calling connection.start method in .NET 4.5 version:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 'A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.'
```

The same code is working in .NET 6.0 version. I have downgraded the version of Apache.NMS to 1.8.0 and Apache.NMS.ACTIVEMQ to 1.8.0.
I want to integrate the code below to consume the data from Amazon MQ in .NET 4.5 version. I am downgrading and upgrading the dependency using NuGet package manager. `Connection.Start` is giving me authentication error.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ssl://url:61617");

ConnectionFactory NMSFactory = new ConnectionFactory(uri);
using (IConnection connection = NMSFactory.CreateConnection("Username", "Password"))
{
    connection.Start();
 
    using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
    {
        IDestination dest = session.GetQueue("QueueName");
        using (IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(dest))
        {
            IMessage message = consumer.Receive();
            Console.WriteLine("Receive message: " + message.NMSMessageId);
            ViewBag.Test = "Received " + message.NMSMessageId;
            //   Console.WriteLine("Message Coming from Active MQ " + message.)

        }
    }
```

Comment: It could be the TLS issue, you can try [enabling TLS 1.2 in the application startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34920429/is-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-enabled-by-default-for-net-4-5-and-net-4-5-1)

Comment: @WiktorZychla :- can you please help, how to include TLS 1.2 as this is MVC project. please guide.

Comment: Go to global.asax.cs, locate Application_Start handler and paste the code there.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks for explaining, I did that but still it is not working. getting same error

Comment: @WiktorZychla - canyou please suggest else to try out. Thanks!

Comment: What's the inner exception of this exception then?

Comment: @WiktorZychla :- inner exception is - The function requested is not supported.

Comment: Exception is - System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 'A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.'

Comment: @WiktorZychla :- added this line in global.asax.cs - System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: The "see inner exception" part of your exception literally means you should consult the inner exception of the exception. Hope you know what inner exception is.

Comment: Hi @WiktorZychla - I know what the inner exception  means, I am not able to post the screenshot here, let me try copy and paste - +  InnerException null System.Exception
  Message "The function requested is not supported" string

Comment: Hi @WiktorZychla :- Can you please let me know some other option so that I can try it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No other suggestions, sorry. The TLS issue was the only obvious one.

Comment: @WiktorZychla :- Thanks for the help, I have figured out that my dot net program is running on 4.5 framework version  which is supporting till TLS12 and Amazon activemq supporting from tls13 that is why I am getting this error.  if you know anything about how  activemq support TLS12?

Comment: You can force 1.3 too, [take a look here](https://www.medo64.com/2020/05/using-tls-1-3-from-net-4-0-application/)

Comment: @WiktorZychla :- I tried that but no luck.

Comment: If you are on an old Windows Server then the client support for the 1.3 can be missing.

Comment: yes, may be, I am using Windows 10 Enterprise.