# How do I do certificate pinning per call in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, security

I understand I can do certificate pinning using `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` on a global scope. All calls to TLS sites will use this callback for checking the certificate. How can I set a certificate validation callback on a per-call basis? I would like to only do certificate pinning for some sites.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795952/626761:

> As a dirty workaround, you could try executing the sites that require a different security protocol in a new appdomain. Static instances are per appdomain, so that should give you the isolation you need.