# Error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." on download a file via HTTPS by using Net.WebClient in powershell

Tags: powershell, web-services, ssl, https, download

I use `powershell` and there is a couple of strings to download an archive via HTTPS:

```
$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile('https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.0.windows.1/MinGit-2.19.0-64-bit.zip', 'd:\Downloads\MinGit-2.19.0-64-bit.zip')
```

Result:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
At line:1 char:1
+ $wc.DownloadFile('https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/dow ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

It doesn't work for GitHub archives but in the same time it does work fine for Dropbox for example:

```
$wc.DownloadFile('https://dropbox.com/download', 'd:\Downloads\dropbox-installer.exe')
```

My Windows 10 System version:

```
> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      17134  0
```

**P.S.**

I was trying to get some solutions from the question [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel) but just got errors like this:

```
The term 'System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

Perhaps, it related to different environment.

Similar other questions:

- ["Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" for Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930471/could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-for-service-account)
- [BufferNotEnough Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087980/buffernotenough-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel/48030563#48030563 and vote for me!

Comment: Thanks. It's working!