# What is the Scope of the System.Net.ServicePointManager Singleton

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core

If I have 2 `Asp.Net` websites running on my machine and 2 `PowerShell` windows open, how many instances of the Static class `System.Net.ServicePointManager` are there?

One per machine? One per Application Domain? One per Process?

Comment: You could try it out and see what happens when writing in one app and reading in another.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5986060/107625).

Comment: Pretty sure it's app domain, but I can't find any proof.

Comment: We have [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit) that mentions app domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SSL3 instead of TLS in a particular HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028486/how-to-use-ssl3-instead-of-tls-in-a-particular-httpwebrequest). Not 100% duplicate, but the accepted answer gives your answer.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, so yes the C# spec does answer the question by searching it for 'application domain' and 'static variables' so I added up-to-date links to the answer @UweKeim pointed to. Which perhaps just leaves me assuming that powershell is one application domain per window. I think my uncertainty stemmed from thinking, network Stuff is potentially a passthrough to the underlying O/S so maybe it was per-machine.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll Powershell isn't just one domain per window, it's different processes. This has nothing to do with *.NET*, it's how the console subsystem on Windows works. What you see isn't powershell. It's a terminal that talks to the Console Host, which in turn talks to Powershell.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll Rich Turner's [Windows Command-Line: Inside the Windows Console](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-inside-the-windows-console/) explains how this works, what the problems were up to now and how this changes in Windows 10, leading up to the new [Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/). With Powershell, and soon the old `CMD` processor, the *process* can easily be on a different machine entirely

Comment: 4: you have 4 processes, none of which share memory. Neither PowerShell nor ASP.NET Core use AppDomains, so that simplifies the question. Having said that, on .NET (not .NET Core) `ServicePointManager` reads defaults from the configuration file and the registry. It never writes anything, but this is one way to get different `ServicePointManager`s to "think" the same. You don't have to fear (or hope) that setting anything in one `ServicePointManager` will influence another, though.

Comment: Moving on then … although you've all commented not answered, I think the Q&A is worth recording?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the docs suggest that the `ServicePointManager` instance is anything other than a standard static instance.

Normal rules should apply: It is destroyed when the Application Domain is destroyed and we infer that there is one-per-Application Domain.

You can verify for `PowerShell` by opening two powershell Windows and typing

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::DefaultConnectionLimit--; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::DefaultConnectionLimit
```

in one of them and

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::DefaultConnectionLimit++; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::DefaultConnectionLimit
```

in the other.